# Bulk Load into SAP HANA Database

Tags: oracle11g, hana, sql-loader

We were using Oracle DB previously in our Datawarehouse setup. We used SQL*Loader utility for bulk loading which was invoked through Informatica. We are shifting our DB to SAP HANA. We are very new to HANA DB. We were looking for similar command line utility in SAP HANA DB for EFFICIENT BULK DATA LOAD. I came across utility with CTL file in SAP HANA.

But problem we are facing is that we need to specify CTL file, path DATA file, path BAD file, path on command line only. Is there way to achieve this? Or do we have a better mechanism in SAP HANA for scheduled bulk loading?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The EXPORT/IMPORT commands of the SAP HANA server are not as versatile as the Oracle command line SQL*Loader.
It's mainly aimed at transports between HANA systems.

For proper ETL you rather want to use either "Smart Data Integration" (https://help.sap.com/hana_options_eim) and/or "Smard Data Acess" (https://help.sap.com/saphelp_hanaplatform/helpdata/en/71/0235120ce744c381176121d4c60b28/content.htm).

Specifically for typical EDW scenarios, there's also the option for "Data Warehousing Foundation" (https://help.sap.com/hana_options_dwf) which provides a lot of functionality to handle mass data. partitioning, data distribution etc.

Knowing many former Oracle users just want a 1:1 swap of tools, I want to give fair warning: data loading & transformation in HANA is a lot less command line based.